# Sell specific Woocommerce items on a specific day and others on a time range

Tags: php, wordpress, time, woocommerce, days

I previously asked if specific items could be restricted to be purchasable on sundays only and  the *"[Sell some products only on a specific day in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867043/sell-some-products-only-on-a-specific-day-in-woocommerce/54868061#54868061)"* provided answer code worked great…

I now have certain items that can be purchased any day but should only be allowed to be purchased between 12:00-2.30 PM London Time.

Can you help modify the previous code to allow for this?

NOTE: I still want to run the previous code by LoicTheAztec as some items are still restricted to Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will allow to have specific items purchasable on sundays and specific items purchasable on a time range (12h to 14h30).

It is a combination of this 2 answers code:

- [Sell some products only on a specific day in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867043/sell-some-products-only-on-a-specific-day-in-woocommerce/54868061#54868061)
- [Enable Woocommerce shop purchases only during a daily time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505345/enable-woocommerce-shop-only-during-a-daily-time-range/54508061#54508061)

Here is that code:

```
// The "sunday" products (setting your product IDS in the array)
function sunday_products() {
    // HERE your product IDs in the array (need to be coma separated)
    return array( 37 );
}

// The 12h to 14h30 products (setting your product IDS in the array)
function time_range_products() {
    // HERE your product IDs in the array (need to be coma separated)
    return array( 53, 57 );
}

// Utility conditional function that check if day is sunday (returns boolean)
function is_sunday() {
    // Set Your shop time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    // If the current day is "sunday" return true (else retun false)
    return ( date('w') == 0 ) ? true : false;
}

// Utility conditional funtion for open hours (returns boolean true when store is open)
function in_time_range() {
    // Set Your shop time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    // Below your shop time and dates settings
    $open_time = mktime('12', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 12:00:00
    $end_time  = mktime('14', '30', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 14:30:00
    $now       = time(); // Current timestamp in seconds

    return ( $now >= $start_time && $now <= $end_time ) ? true : false;
}


// Enable purchases for specific items on sundays only
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'enable_specific_products_on_sundays', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'enable_specific_products_on_sundays', 10, 2 );
function enable_specific_products_on_sundays( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Enable purchases for specific defined item only on sunday
    if( ! is_sunday() && in_array( $product->get_id(), sunday_products() ) )
        $purchasable = false;

    // Enable purchases for specific defined item only from 12h to 14h30
    if( ! in_time_range() && in_array( $product->get_id(), time_range_products() ) )
        $purchasable = false;

    return $purchasable;
}

// Add a notice in specific products outside sundays
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'filter_before_single_product' );
function filter_before_single_product() {
    global $product;

    // For sundays product
    if( ! is_sunday() && in_array( $product->get_id(), sunday_products() ) ) {
        wc_print_notice( __( 'This product is only purchasable on sundays', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    } 
    // For hour range product
    elseif( ! in_time_range() && in_array( $product->get_id(), time_range_products() ) ) {
        wc_print_notice( __( 'This product is only purchasable between 12 AM and 2h30 PM', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
}

// IN CASE OF (but not needed): Cart and checkout validation + error message
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'conditionally_allowing_checkout' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'conditionally_allowing_checkout' );
function conditionally_allowing_checkout() {
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Check cart items
        if( ! is_sunday() && in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), sunday_products() ) ){
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(__("%s can be only purchase on sundays.", "woocommerce"), $cart_item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
            break;
        }
        else if( ! in_time_range() && in_array( $cart_item['data']->get_id(), time_range_products() ) ){
            wc_add_notice( sprintf(__("%s can be only purchase between 12 AM and 2h30 PM.", "woocommerce"), $cart_item['data']->get_name() ), 'error' );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.